# Why is "preventing" correct in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds

I have read this sentence

> In 1868, Sioux leaders signed a [a]**treaty** [b]**preventing** whites from [c]**travelling** through the Sioux [d]**territorial**"

I know the answer is territorial, but I thought it had to be preventing. Could you explain to me? Why is "preventing" correct?

Comment: I can't understand why the mistake is d ( territorial), could you explain it to me?

Comment: The sentence probably should be saying **thorough the Sioux territory**. You need a noun there. The word **territorial** is more commonly used as an adjective (although **territorial** can also be a noun, it means something different and definitely wouldn't work in your context) which means relating to the ownership of an area of land.

Comment: Sorry, thorough the word would be wrong here in any case. To travel ***through*** Sioux territory. Kate, you have not reproduced the sentence correctly. Please fix it.

Comment: @Lambie That's right. It should be **through**. That was my bad.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin No worries. The OP still needs to correct herself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say this, but I assume you are asking:

> I have been asked to identify which word is incorrect. I have 4 choices - a, b, c and d.  The correct choice is "territorial".  I think the correct choice is "preventing".  Why is the correct answer "territorial" and not "preventing"?

Grammatically "territorial" should be "territory."

When you say "the", I believe the next word that should follow is a noun.  "Territorial" is an adjective.  So you can't say "the territorial".

"Territory" is a noun, so you can say "the territory".

"Preventing" is used correctly here.  If that doesn't make sense to you, try using one of these words: "forbidding", "disallowing", "stopping".  All of those words are similar to "preventing" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

As “Words Like Jared” explains, “territorial” is wrong; that is the answer to the question.  However, “preventing” is also wrong.  The correct word is “prohibiting” (and delete “from”).  If the whites comply with [obey] the treaty, then they will not travel as described… but neither the treaty itself, nor the writing in it, actually *prevents* them from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

*Preventing ... territorial* is a participial clause modifying *treaty*. It is introduced by the participle *preventing*.

I ignore the question of *territorial* which you make clear that you understand is wrong. But what's probably confusing the other answerers is that you didn't say that the problem was identifying the error.